# What should i use Nginx html app or/and load balancing?

Tags: html, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

i have a index.html application who execute js application with nginx.
https://github.com/daleharvey/pacman

I would like to dockerize this application with 3 containers of app and a load balancing who chose with round robin algorithms 1 of 3 containers.

But my html app is with nginx, my load balancing it's nginx too ?

my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  pacman1:
    build: ./pacman
  pacman2:
    build: ./pacman
  pacman3:
    build: ./pacman

   nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: production_nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports: ['8000:80']

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports: ['6379']
```

my Dockerfile of html app:

```
#Start with current nginx
FROM nginx:latest
#Update package manager and install git
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        git
#Clean the html root dir
RUN rm -R /usr/share/nginx/html/
#Clone pacman app from git
RUN git clone https://github.com/daleharvey/pacman.git /usr/share/nginx/html/
#Modify files for web serving
RUN chmod -R 755 /usr/share/nginx/html/*
RUN chown -R www-data /usr/share/nginx/html/*

EXPOSE 3000

#USAGE:
# docker run --name pacman -d -p 8080:80 pacman
```

my nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

        upstream mysite {
              least_conn;
              server pacman1:3000;
              server pacman2:3000;
              server pacman3:3000;
        }

        server {
          listen 8080;
              server_name _;
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
          index index.html;
              location / {
                proxy_pass http://mysite;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
              }
        }
}
```

Please, why it's doesn't work ? because nginx have default port 80 ? How can i run my html app without nginx ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is what is running your HTML app. You will need Nginx (good choice) or some other web server such as Apache to run the HTML app.

You could build your app with NodeJS or something which includes a server however using Nginx is probably the best solution.

Comment: yes, but i want proxy and loadbalancing on my html app. should i use traefik with nginx ? or nginx proxy with nginx html app ?

Comment: I don't have any experience with traefik but you could use something like HAProxy or nginx as you said. My question is a bit more high level on why do you need this load balanced? This config would put the containers on the same machine. Maybe instead what you should be looking at is using docker swarm or Kubernetes so you can scale `pacman`.